# How to enable vscode to auto acquire local type for root folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently I have 2 projects, both with the same structure: all source goes to folder `src`.

`src
└───folder1
│   │   file011.js
│   │   file012.js
│   └───...
└───folder2
│   │   file021.js
│   └───file022.js
│
│   services.js`

Somewhere deep down in `src` folder, I have

```
import { ClassA} from 'services';
```

where services is direct child file inside `src` folder.

In 1 project, opened with Code-Insiders, i get full intellisense on `ClassA`, but nothing in the other. Wonder what causes the different behavior between the 2 and how I can adjust that.

Comment: Do you have a `jsconfig.json` in either project?

Comment: Yes i have both. Using similar configs

Comment: Ok. It'd probably be easier to diagnose the problem in a VSCode issue rather than on SO: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new Please share the two jsconfig files or, even better, the project itself and I'll try taking a look

Comment: Its nice but i lost interest in figuring them out. Will update here later if necessary. thanks for your help.